# ADODB run-time error with execute method fail

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, adodb

Strange thing with an SQL query execution.
I'm trying to query Access DB from Excel VBA
The following query runs ok
`"SELECT * FROM LL_domain"`

While executing of this simple query  `"SELECT * FROM LL_domain WHERE domain = 'de"` I get a run-time error.

I copied the query into Access query frame and it works ok. Seems, it's not a syntax problem.
With an other provider for the connection object I get the same error.

What can be a reason for that?

some of my code:

```
Function foo (ByRef dBase as Object) as Boolean
Dim myConn2 as Object
    Set myConn2 = CN.getCN_Ace16(dBase.fileDB.path)
    Me.marketID = getMarketID(myConn2)
End Function

Function getCN_Ace16(ByVal dbPath As String) As Object
    Set getCN_Ace16 = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    getCN_Ace16.connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
End Function

Function getMarketID(ByRef myConn As Object) As String
Dim RS As Object
    myConn.Open
    Set RS = myConn.Execute("SELECT * FROM LL_domain WHERE domain = 'de'")
    ......
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: try `WHERE [domain] = 'de'`

Comment: @CDP1802, thank you for the tip, I tried but it didn't work as well. Then problem was with a word domain. When I changed the field name the problem was solved. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMAIN` is an [Access database engine reserved word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2#__toc262648755)

Your query may work if you bracket the field name or qualify the name like one of these examples ...

```sql
SELECT * FROM LL_domain WHERE [domain] = 'de'
SELECT * FROM LL_domain WHERE LL_domain.domain = 'de'
SELECT * FROM LL_domain AS ll WHERE ll.domain = 'de'
```

However, if it were me, I would prefer to change the field name to something which is not a reserved word.  Allen Browne provided a comprehensive list of [Problem names and reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html)